# splitting data in to test train data when there is unbalance of data

Tags: python, machine-learning

i have an unbalanced data set which has two categorical values. one has around 500 values of a particular class and other is only one single datapoint with another class.Now i would like to split this data into test train with 80-20 ratio. but since this is unbalanced , i would like to have the second class to be present in both the test and train data.
I tried using the test-train-split from sklearn, but it does not give the second class data to be present in both of them. I even tried the stratified shuffle split, but that was also not giving data as i thought.
Is there any way we can split the data from a data frame forcing both the test and train datasets to have the single datapoint?. I am new to python so having difficulty figuring it out.

the data looks like:

a  b  c  d  label

1  0  0  1   1

1  1  1  0   1

..........
........

1  0  0   1  0.

the label has only 1 and 0 but the 0 is only one single observation but the rest of the 500 data points are having label as 1

Comment: Give some lines of your data and your expected output to get help.

Answer (score 0):

With the information you gave, I suggest you to down/over sampling the data in order to give an equal weight to both your classes and then split your dataset as you like. Take a look at this [library](http://contrib.scikit-learn.org/imbalanced-learn/stable/index.html) exposing different algorithms to deal with unbalanced data in python

Answer (score 0):

Try to do oversampling as you have less amount of data points. Or else you can use neural network preferably MLP, That works fine with unbalanced data.